# how to create elasticsearch tokens for a unique use case for text value?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, tokenize, regex-group

I have a use case where i want to tokenise emailId with

Category 1
words separated by punctuations & prefix tokens

Category 2
words separated by punctuations & prefix tokens & along with punctuation

for example. email - **ona.ki@gl.co**

I want to know whether the the following tokens for the above emailid is possible to achieve.

on, ona, ona., ona.k, ona.ki, ona.ki@, ona.ki@g, ona.ki@gl, ona.ki@gl., ona.ki@gl.c, ona.ki@gl.co

.k, .ki, .ki@, .ki@g, .ki@gl, .ki@gl. , .ki@gl.c, .ki@gl.co

ki, ki@, ki@g, ki@gl, ki@gl. , ki@gl.c, ki@gl.co

@g, @gl, @gl. , @gl.c, @gl.co

gl, gl., gl.c, gl.co

.c, .co

co

Use case example for **ona.ki@gl.co**

**ona.k** - *should match*

**na.k** - *should not match*

**.ki@** - *Should match*

**ki@** - *Should match*

**i@** - *Should not match*

The reason why i want to tokenise this way is because consider there are 2 doc with text values

1. ona.ki@gl.com
2. mona.gh@gl.com
   When the user types on, ona, ... i want to fetch and show only ona.ki@gl.com not the other one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already tried to use prefix query?

Comment: I tried prefix query. But that will only fetch the tokens in first line. Not the remaining tokens starting from .k, .ki, .ki@,  etc...

Comment: tokenizer ngram, tried?

Comment: Yes. I have. That will fetch more matches that doesn't suit my use case. for example ngram would fetch document even when searched for na.ki, which i dont want only searched ona.ki