# How to highlight the matching subtext in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am getting expected highlighting of substring matching user search keyword in companyName and country fields. However in emailId field instead of highlighting the substring the entire field is getting highlighted.

**Query**

```
POST customers-index/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "must": [
      {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "state",
          "fields": [
            "emailId.autocomplete",
            "companyName.autocomplete",
            "country.autocomplete"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "emailId.autocomplete": {},
      "companyName.autocomplete": {},
      "country.autocomplete": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "emailId",
    "companyName",
    "country"
  ]
}
```

**Response**

```
[
 {
        "_index" : "customers-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c44aefde-22b1-471d-9159-a092e5c604f6",
        "_score" : 14.853605,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "Ethiopia",
          "companyName" : "La Galtoara, Inc.",
          "emailId" : [
            "galtoara@state.gov"
          ]
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "emailId.autocomplete" : [
            "<em>galtoara@state.gov</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "customers-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "f76ecf0a-3e7d-41f9-a96f-83c66698f2d1",
        "_score" : 3.6045084,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "Philippines",
          "companyName" : "Belgone State Medical, Inc.",
          "emailId" : [
            "dopasdfd@apple.com"
          ]
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "companyName.autocomplete" : [
            "Belgone <em>State</em> Medical, Inc."
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "customers-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "b41b1c0c-e84d-4424-a862-38b10d380d23",
        "_score" : 2.1431046,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "United States",
          "companyName" : "DFDFDF Brands Limited",
          "emailId" : [
            "adfadfad@godaddy.com"
          ]
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "country.autocomplete" : [
            "United <em>State</em>s"
          ]
        }
      }
```

And the settings and mappings are as follows for emailId field

**Mapping**

```
{
  "emailId": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "autocomplete": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete_email_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
  }
}
```

**Settings**

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "email_filter": {
        "type": "pattern_capture",
        "preserve_original": "true",
        "patterns": [
          """(?=([@|\.|\!|\#|\$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|\/|\=|\?|\^|\_|\`|\{|\||\}|\~](.+)))"""
        ]
      },
      "starts_with_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": "1",
        "max_gram": "100"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "search_analyzer": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
      },
      "index_analyzer": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "index_analyzer"
      },
      "autocomplete_email_analyzer": {
        "filter": [
          "email_filter",
          "unique",
          "starts_with_filter",
          "lowercase"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "autocomplete_email_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "normalizer": {
      "lowercase_normalizer": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": []
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "autocomplete_email_tokenizer": {
        "type": "uax_url_email"
      },
      "index_analyzer": {
        "token_chars": [
          "letter",
          "digit",
          "whitespace",
          "punctuation",
          "symbol"
        ],
        "min_gram": "2",
        "type": "ngram",
        "max_gram": "30"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I have added the mappings and settings relevant to emailId field alone as it is the field of concern.

As we can notice from the response, companyName and country fields are highlighted on the substring matching search query level however, emailId field is highlighted entirely.

How to highlight only the substring in the emailId field also. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. There is no tokenizer called `index_analyzer` that is used by `index_analyzer` and normalizers that you are using are not present in your settings.

Comment: Hi @imotov, Thanks for taking time to check it. I have added tokenizers and normalizers that were missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem that [pattern capture filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) is warning about.

Let's dig into the source of the problem. During the search no information about why a particular query matched a particular records is preserved. So, highlighters need to reverse-engineer this process, which is quite complicated and not very precise.

Analyzers makes this quite difficult since they can completely change the original text. The information that connects the resulting tokens with the position in the original text is stored with each token in form of start and end offsets of each tokens by tokenizer. After a tokenizer placed this information, it can be updated by some filters, but not all filters do it for various reasons. For example, the `word_delimiter` filter will update the offset information:

```
POST test/_analyze
{
  "text": [
    "test@example.org"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
  "filter": [ "word_delimiter" ]
}
```

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "example",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "org",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But `ngram` and `pattern_capture` will simply copy the position of the original token to all tokens they will produce from it. That is exactly what happens in your case. Your tokenizer produces a single token that spans the entire email address and all other filters just copy this information into all tokens they produce:

```
POST customers-index/_analyze
{
  "text": ["galtoara@state.gov"],
  "field": "emailId.autocomplete"
}
```

As you can see all these tokens correspond to the original token with position 0 and start offset of 0 and end offset of 18, which is the entire string. So highlighter matches one of these token and highlights the whole string.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "g",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
.... 
    {
      "token": "state",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
....
,
    {
      "token": "gov",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

In other words, if you fix the offsets that your analyzer is producing, you will fix the highlighting. I don't know all the reasons why you added all these filters so I cannot offer you a complete solution that will work for all your use-case, but I hopefully the following example will give you some ideas. You can start with replacing filter that don't updated offsets with filters that do. For example:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": [
    "test@example.org"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "word_delimiter"
    },
    {
      "type": "lowercase"
    },
    {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": "1",
      "max_gram": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

This filter will produce 3 tokens with correct offsets which will keep the relationships between prefixes and the string these prefixes came from:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "g",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ga",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "gal",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 0
    },
....
   {
      "token": "state",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 1
    },
.....
    {
      "token": "gov",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

You can achieve a similar effect by adding ngram tokenizer instead of using it as a filter. Here is a complete example:

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "max_ngram_diff": 50,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": "true",
          "patterns": [
            """(?=([@|\.|\!|\#|\$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|\/|\=|\?|\^|\_|\`|\{|\||\}|\~](.+)))"""
            ]
        },
        "starts_with_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "100"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "highlighting_email_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "word_delimiter",
            "lowercase",
            "starts_with_filter"
            ]
        },
        "search_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "index_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "index_analyzer"
        },
        "autocomplete_email_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "email_filter",
            "unique",
            "starts_with_filter",
            "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "autocomplete_email_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": []
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_email_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        },
        "index_analyzer": {
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
            ],
            "min_gram": "2",
            "type": "ngram",
            "max_gram": "30"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "emailId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete_email_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          },
          "highlighting": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "highlighting_email_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"country":"Ethiopia","companyName":"La Galtoara, Inc.","emailId":["galtoara@state.gov"]}
{"index":{}}
{"country":"Philippines","companyName":"Belgone State Medical, Inc.","emailId":["dopasdfd@apple.com"]}
{"index":{}}
{"country":"United States","companyName":"DFDFDF Brands Limited","emailId":["adfadfad@godaddy.com"]}


POST test/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "state",
            "fields": [
              "emailId.highlighting",
              "companyName.autocomplete",
              "country.autocomplete"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "emailId.highlighting": {},
      "companyName.autocomplete": {},
      "country.autocomplete": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "emailId",
    "companyName",
    "country"
  ]
}
```

This will give you

```
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "ckGiHIsBImXKNSrQCBEW",
        "_score": 1.014292,
        "_source": {
          "country": "Ethiopia",
          "companyName": "La Galtoara, Inc.",
          "emailId": [
            "galtoara@state.gov"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "emailId.highlighting": [
            "galtoara@<em>state</em>.gov"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi @imotov . Thanks for taking time to explain the problem and suggesting a possible solution. To answer your question why i use this pattern capture is because i have unique use case where default analyzer, tokenizer will not be a help. I will cross check the highlight specifc field and the analyzer you have shared for it and see if it will match my use case.

Comment: I am afraid the highlighter anaylzer will highlight text if the substring is present in other place also instead of being in start of the search text or right after special characters in emailid filed (my use case). I will verify that. The following is the post i had added for my use case 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346506/how-to-create-elasticsearch-tokens-for-a-unique-use-case-for-text-value
The analyzer autocomplete_email_analyzer is the one that helped me achieve it

Comment: This might call for a custom tokenizer plugin that splits the right way and respects offsets.

Comment: Okay @imotov. Thanks for the comment. I will verify the same.